# xslt: iterate over a fixed set of tags, but need a string label for output

Tags: xml, xslt

I'd like to iterate a fixed list. But this list contains path to select from the source document and a label which should appear in the destination document.

So in my toy example: I'd like to iterate on profiles (sorry for the stupid name choices):

- first profile is called `boo` and is located at `root/boo` and labeled `bootype`
- second profile is called `omg` and is located at `root/omg` and labeled `OMGtype`

Source document:

```xml
<root>
    <omg>
        <name>hello omg</name>
    </omg>
    <boo>
        <name>hello boo</name>
    </boo>
</root>
```

xslt

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:variable name="profileTypes">
                <profileType>
                    <inner>boo</inner>
                    <type>bootype</type>
                </profileType>
                <profileType>
                    <inner>omg</inner>
                    <type>OMGtype</type>
                </profileType>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="profiles" select="document('')//xsl:variable[@name='profileTypes']/profileType"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="root/*[name()=$profiles/inner]">
                <out>
                    <name>
                        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                    </name>
                    <type>TODO: what should I do here?</type>
                </out>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Desired output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <out>
    <name>hello omg</name>
    <type>OMGtype</type>
  </out>
  <out>
    <name>hello boo</name>
    <type>bootype</type>
  </out>
</root>
```

Comment: You say you want to iterate on profiles, but you actually iterate on the XML root's child nodes. It may not matter in the given example, but it could make a difference in another. -- Also, are you limited to XSLT 1.0? If so, which processor?

Comment: Ok, should have chosen better names. `boo` and `omg` are the two profile instances.

Comment: Well, this is still a too abstract example and there is no clear statement of the logic that needs to be applied here. Note that your test would pass a "profile instance" whose path is `/root/boos/omg`.

Comment: The example is rather concrete, the point is that the input is a constraint, so you cannot juggle with that.
Thanks for pointing that out, made me understand xslt better.

In my case that is not possible due to the schema of the input.

I will simplify and split this part of the example to another question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the original document when iterating over a variable

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:variable name="profileTypes">
                <profileType id='booid'>
                    <inner>boo</inner>
                    <type>bootype</type>
                </profileType>
                <profileType id='omgid'>
                    <inner>omg</inner>
                    <type>OMGtype</type>
                </profileType>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="doc" select="/"/>
            <xsl:variable name="profiles" select="document('')//xsl:variable[@name='profileTypes']/profileType"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$profiles">

                <xsl:variable name="innerPath" select="inner"/>
                <xsl:variable name="type" select="type"/>

                <xsl:for-each select="$doc/root/*[name()=$innerPath]">
                    <out>
                        <type>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$type"/>
                        </type>
                        <name>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </name>
                    </out>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```